# awk: split input string of numbers and do maths on individual character

Tags: bash, awk

I have to take a number as the first argument and do maths on individual digits.

The program below is supposed to output all the individual digits.

```
INPUT=$1
doMath() {
  awk '{split('$INPUT',a,"");printf "'${@$INPUT}'"}' 
}
doMath
```

I execute it with command `./armstrong_numbers.sh 657823` and get error *'{split('$INPUT',a,"");printf "'${@$INPUT}'"}': bad substitution*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up `bash` with `awk` arrays.

Your example command splits the `$INPUT` into an **`awk`** array named `a`.
Also, you need to use `BEGIN{...}` instead of `{...}`, otherwise `awk` waits for input, which you don't give.

Try this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{split('$INPUT',a,""); for (k in a) print a[k]; }'
```

or better set the variable with `-v` to avoid problems with bad input.

```
awk -v "input=$INPUT" \
  'BEGIN{split(input,a,""); for (k in a) print a[k]; }'
```

Output is:

```
6
5
7
8
2
3
```

Or just do everything in `bash`:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#INPUT};i++)); do
  echo ${INPUT:$i:1};
done
```

Comment: I want the awk array `a` to be in scope of bash so that I can use bash commands to do math on individual digits. Will it be possible to it outside `awk '...'`?

Comment: why do you use awk and not bash then in the first place?

Comment: I get the point, I'll try with bash only.

Comment: added a bash way to do it